# Create a .gz file from list of S3 files

Tags: php, zlib

I am trying to create a `.gz` file from a list of `s3` files. I am able to get a list of the files and read the content of the files. I just can't figure out how to write them to a `.gz` file. Also is there a way for me to write them to memory instead of a file before downloading?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
$files = $disk->files('s3/files');
$outFile = 'opt.gz';
$gz = gzopen($outFile, 'w9');
// Add the items to the gz file
foreach($files as $file) {
    $content = $disk->getDriver()->read($file);
    file_put_contents($outFile, gzencode($content), FILE_APPEND);
}
gzclose($gz);

// Download the file
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($outFile).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($outFile));
readfile($outFile);
```

Comment: Gzip operates on a stream of bytes and has no concept of "files". You'll probably want to stream it through an archiver like `tar` that is aware of such things, and *then* gzip it.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned this, so I went with a `ZipArchive`.